# Regex - SQL statement

Tags: java, regex

It is only a very simple SQL parsing process, no `HAVING`, `ORDER BY` or `GROUP BY` would be in the statement that needs to be parsed, but something about matching an asterisk in SELECT part won't work (e.g. `SELECT * .......`)

Here's the code part:

```
String span="SELECT * FROM table1 t, table2";

span=span.toUpperCase();

System.out.println(span);

// Segments
String column="(\\w+\\s*(\\w+\\s*){0,1})";

String columns=column+"(,\\s*"+column+")*";

String ownerenable="((\\w+\\.){0,1}\\w+\\s*(\\w+\\s*){0,1})";

String ownerenables=ownerenable+"(,\\s*"+ownerenable+")*";

String from="FROM\\s+"+columns;

String condition="(\\w+\\.){0,1}\\w+\\s*(=|<|>|LIKE|IS)\\s*'?(\\w+\\.){0,1}[\\w%]+'?";

String conditions=condition+"(\\s+(AND|OR)\\s*"+condition+"\\s*)*";

String where="(WHERE\\s+"+conditions+"){0,1}";

String pattern = "SELECT\\s+(\\*|" + ownerenables + "\\s+" + from + ")\\s+" + where + "\\s*" + "(;){0,1}";

System.out.println(pattern);
System.out.println(span.matches(pattern));
```

**Now if I set span to something like**

```
"SELECT t.id, product p FROM table1 t, table2 WHERE t.id=10;"
```

The match result would be true

================================

**But if I set it to something like this:**

```
"SELECT * FROM table1 t, table2 WHERE t.id=10;"
```

(It's an asterisk I'm using for the SELECT)

It won't work in this case

Am I doing anything wrong about that asterisk?

Comment: I'm not convinced that a regexp is the right tool to use here...

Comment: @Maurice Perry Yes...But I'm just doing a simple test here and the problem came....

Comment: OK. you can use ? instead of {0,1}

Comment: @RushSykes since `*` is a meta-character it should be backslashed "\"* . It will match `*`.  You need to add it to your `ownerenable`. However it will be quite tricky to do it with regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parenthesis must be closed **before** the `from`:

```
String pattern = "SELECT\\s+(\\*|" + ownerenables + ")\\s+" + from + "\\s+" + where + "\\s*" + "(;){0,1}";
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  I tried this but it still won't match

Comment: Hi. I tried it, and it DOES match (at least the example you gave above)

Comment: Oops, so it says true on your computer but not on mine... Strange....  I'll go and check again, thanks

Comment: Oh yes......It's my fault, when i was doing some other tests just now I forgot about the cases where there are  `WHERE` conditions, hha thanks! And btw I think, ah at least I thought the parenthesis is ok with the position after **from**, now it's proven wrong, and why is that?

Answer (score 0):

you select table2 but don't select anything from it. you must specify the join between table1 and table2 if you want to do an * select.

This is your issue.

Comment: Ah here the join is not necessary, even in the real SQL system I can still do that, it't just that the result would be of no significance.